# Get Text from dropdown

Tags: asp.net

I have one page which has Only one Dropdown name called  "MydropDown".My submitted form i can get value of selected dropdown by

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MydropDown"];
```

but i need Text not value how can i get this 
Plz help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its not a control, there is no way to get the text other than put the text into the value field.